# Multi-index DataFrame to a Sequence of Adjacency Matrices (Numpy 3D Array)

Tags: pandas, multi-index, adjacency-matrix

I would like to convert a multi-index data frame into a sequence of adjacency matrices, or a 3d Numpy array indexed by the time coordinates.

Here is the data frame:

```
Boxes = {'Date': ['2016-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 
        '2016-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-01-01 12:00:00', '2016-01-01 12:00:00', 
        '2016-01-01 12:00:00', '2016-01-01 17:54:00', '2016-01-01 22:44:00'],
         'From': ['Green','Green','Green','Blue','Blue','Red','Red','Red'],
         'To': ['Rectangle','Rectangle','Square','Rectangle','Square','Square','Square','Rectangle'],
         'Qty': ['12', '3', '43', '125', '34', '76', '9', '222' ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(Boxes, columns= ['Date', 'From', 'To', 'Qty'])
```

I can create the multi-index data frame by

```
dups = df.pivot_table(index=['Date'], columns = ['From', 'To'], values = ['Qty'], aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
```

What is the best way to convert this multi-index data frame into a sequence of adjacency matrices that are indexed by the time component? or, to create a 3d numpy array as follows:

```
[[[ 0.   0.   0.   15.  43.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[ 0.   0.   0.   0.    0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   125.  34.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.    76.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.    0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.    0.]]

 [[ 0.   0.   0.   0.    0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.    0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.    9.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.    0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.    0.]]

 [[ 0.   0.   0.   0.      0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.      0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   222.    0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.      0.]
  [ 0.   0.   0.   0.      0.]]]
```

Since these matrices will be sparse, may be an adjacency list would be a more efficient answer. Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: A numpy array of shape `4 x 5 x 5`. `4` is the time index (`4` distinct times) and `5` is the number of nodes (`Green`, `Blue`, `Red, `Rectangle`, `Square` ). The entries of the adjacency matrix at each time stamp are sum of the values in the `Qty` column. Hope that is clear!

Comment: would you like create that matrix base on your dups dataframe ?

Comment: Yes, preferably. But if that is too complicated, from `df` data frame works too.

Comment: I mean just show us the expected output .

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide the expected output , I can only offer the way convert to 3 d array

```
d1 = len(dups.columns.get_level_values(1).unique())
d2 = len(dups.columns.get_level_values(2).unique())
a = dups.values.reshape((len(dups), d1, d2))
a.shape
Out[450]: (4, 3, 2)
```

Comment: @SMD why you have 5 dimension

Comment: May be my naming convention is not clear enough, but the point is that there are `5` nodes: `Green`, `Blue`, `Red`, `Rectangle`, `Square`. The graph is a directed graph, meaning that the adjacency matrices are not necessarily symmetric.